# Login second time gives Error in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

When I try to login in prestashop 1.7 backend second time it gives me below error

Premature end of data in tag module line 1 in country_module_list.xml file.

Any One solve this error? Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you please specify the version of PrestaShop? Are you talking about the lastest one (1.7.0.4) ?

Comment: yes.I am talking about 1.7.0.4.

Comment: Did you install PrestaShop 1.7.0.4 directly or upgrade from another older version?

Comment: I have installed directly but when i opened it on next day error comes up, so after searching i found below solution i don't know it is right way or not but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for while I just found below solution,
In prestashop directory structure,
There is a "**config/xml**" folder in which "**default_country_modules_list.xml**" is there..

It is generated every time when auto upgraded prestashop.
So i just deleted it and after generating new "default_country_modules_list.xml" , login problem has been solved.